Interior button for my car central lock system
My car has 3/4 doors with a motorised lock/unlock system with the driver's door being the only one without. That is how it came from the factory. Later I installed a remote lock/unlock system by retrofitting an electric actuator on the driver's side door. Thereby with the remote I could lock/unlock all 4 doors now. This works perfectly.
However, lately, I wanted to install a lock/unlock button inside the car, closer to the front passenger side. So that other passengers inside the can could easily unlock/lock the doors using this button.
The actuator I installed has two wires. It triggers lock/unlock by swapping polarity (12v) between these two wies.

The following is the wiring diagram from my existing remote lock/unlock system. Showing how to wire the type of door actuator I have. And it is how currently been wired.

I bought this button. It has two non-latching push buttons.

I developed this relay+diode combination circuit to connect the existing wire harness from the remote lock/unlock system.
The red-circled circuit represents the remote lock/unlock system.

If you would like to simulate the circuit, here are the link and the file to import.
I had to use a separate set of relays, otherwise, it would put both polarities together.
I have built the circuit on a prototype board and failed as the main 12v power rails fuse keeps blowing. when I press the buttons on the new switch, indicating a dead short or maybe 15Amp could not tolerate the current. No clue.
Does anyone have a better suggestion for what I'm trying to achieve?
Or do you see anything that I'm doing wrong?
Thank you in advance.

This is a Q and A site, so you need to ask a crisp question else this will get closed. I would suggest you spend some time learning how to draw a schematic. Currently your diagram shows how you’ve interconnected the relays etc but it does not sufficiently convey how it is to work. Whilst there is nothing wrong with using diodes and relays - does your circled section work as you intended?  If not, then asking why it doesn’t work would form a question.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

This can be greatly simplified by the use of a DPDT relay:

The DPDT relay (the one at the bottom) reverses the polarity to the actuator, while the SPST (the one at the top, SPDT pictured because that's all Falstad has) disconnects the actuator so it isn't on all the time.
Note that the "Unlock" signal has preference when both buttons are pressed at once.
Falstad data (for use with 'Import From Text...'):
$ 1 0.000005 10.20027730826997 50 5 43 5e-11
w 208 0 256 0 0
w 336 160 336 192 0
w 288 96 288 128 0
w 144 192 272 192 0
w 336 -64 336 -48 0
w 272 -64 272 -48 0
425 272 -64 336 -64 0 Actuator 0.2 -0.000011999757604872264 0.02 20 0.015 0.005 0 0 0
w 32 0 32 64 0
w 32 -32 32 0 0
w 336 64 336 96 0
w 336 -48 336 64 0
w 320 192 320 160 0
w 336 160 336 96 0
w 368 192 368 128 0
w 288 192 288 128 0
178 304 288 304 192 6 2 0.2 -5.798976535398963e-40 0.05 1000000 0.02 20 0.015 0.005 0
R 304 288 304 336 0 0 40 12 0 0 0.5
w 208 64 208 0 0
w 112 64 144 64 0
w 112 0 144 0 0
d 144 64 208 64 2 default
d 144 0 208 0 2 default
x 43 37 116 40 4 24 Unlock
x 57 -36 107 -33 4 24 Lock
R 32 -32 32 -80 0 0 40 12 0 0 0.5
s 32 64 112 64 0 1 true
s 32 0 112 0 0 1 true
g 256 96 256 128 0 0
g 272 288 272 320 0 0
g 352 288 352 320 0 0
w 272 0 272 -48 0
178 288 96 288 0 6 1 0.2 -4.286977522688796e-40 0.05 1000000 0.02 20 0.015 0.005 0
w 320 160 336 160 0
w 368 128 288 128 0
d 144 64 144 192 2 default


One relay per direction should be enough. If both directions, lock and unlock are pressed, the voltage across the actuator is 0 V again, the same as if no button is pressed.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

Thanks, but this cannot be achieved as the LOCK1, and UNLOCK1 are built into the remote door opener unit. Something like this  https://thecarguys.pk/cdn/shop/products/20.jpg?v=1705825150&width=1946

You provided a schematic "diagram 4" which is compatible with my schematic if you don't connect orange and orange/black to GND, which is already not shown in the diagram 4. You wrote, that this is the schematic of your existing system. So isn't it?

I'm sorry if I made you understand wrong. The "Diagram 4" is from the unit manufacture manual and when I tested the connections with a multimeter, both NC (orange and orange/black) were connected to GND. That is how the current system is. In the Circuit Simulator Applet picture, I circled an area (in RED colour) that simulated the unit operation. Assuming LOCK2/UNLOCK2 is my new button, can you explain how I would connect its wires according to your diagram in the car? Thank you for your time.
